# Why would speed of light be directional if spacetime is discrete?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, discrete

In Feynman's [Simulating Physics with Computers](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/Feynman.pdf), Feynman states that

> "we might change the idea that space is
>   continuous to the idea that space perhaps is a simple lattice and everything
>   is discrete" ... "the speed of light would
>   depend slightly on the direction, and there might be other anisotropies in
>   the physics that we could detect experimentally"

Why does the existence of the lattice of spacetime (if any) affect the isotropy of speed of light?

The other theories which might question the validity of the Lorentz Invariance of speed of light are Loop Quantum Gravity and String Theory ([a paper on this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6191)), which do not seem to directly be associated with the lattice hypothesis, although the string theory might be similar to a lattice-like spacetime.

Comment: He is just winging it here and not very well. The first and most important thing that a naive lattice would do would be to break relativity. This already happens in the Galilean case since we now have a preferred rest system. Neither LQG nor string theory are on lattices. We do have important examples of this in physics, of course: optics and phonons in crystals.

Comment: Somewhere I've read here, that there is experimental evidence that the spacetime is continous at least until trillionths of the Planck length.

Comment: @peterh: That is a question that has raised considerable discussions among the specialists. There is no consensus on it and all experiments that indicate such a thing seem to work of rather naive assumptions. On the other hand, the Planck length is nothing but intellectual nonsense at this point. There is not one data point that indicates that anything is there there.

Comment: @CuriousOne: why is he winging it by rejecting a simple lattice which you are also rejecting?  By saying "simple lattice" he is actually leaving other models open in this quotation.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: For one thing there is no such thing as "a simple lattice". Even in three dimensions there are 230 space groups and that's not even counting the infinite number of quasi-crystal lattices. Icosahedral systems, for instance, look almost isotropic, already. He also says nothing about what the dynamics on this lattice looks like and I am fairly sure that one could construct models that would be very hard to test unless one can come very close to the edge of the Brillouin zone.

Comment: @CuriousOne you know as well as I do that "a simple lattice" means "a lattice with nodes at cartesian points, and edges connecting nearest-neighbor nodes"

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I have done crystallography once, so to me a simple lattice is one of _many_ possibilities. Let's just admit that Feynman was often oversimplifying things and that that's OK, for the level of his audience. As a general question what he suggests is not nearly that simple.

Comment: @CuriousOne: and the detail of the example still belies the overall point, there would still be anisotropies in the propogation of fields, because it would matter whether you were moving along an edge or not.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Waves aren't moving along edges.

Comment: @CuriousOne: and in lattice QCD, you're not talking about propogating waves anymore, really.  You're writing difference equations to approximate the changes in fields.  the light wave is an emergent property in the continuum limit.

Comment: Only for wavelengths near the discrete length scale would you notice any anisotropy. For any actually experimentally accessible wavelengths you'd notice nothing at all. Moreover one can concieve of discrete space-time which is more of a random graph which need only be 3d on longer scales, and might any and even fractional dimension near it's intrinsic scale. That would make the search for anisotropy completely pointless; although it might leave frequency dependent effects.

Comment: As for a discrete space-time implying a preferred rest frame; no not really. The central finding of relativity is that we can't establish a preferred frame with local measurements; not that one cannot or may not exist. And none of that changes per se given a discrete space-time.